# Динамическое изменение стилей

Tags: html, css, vue.js, scss

Можно ли как-нибудь, помимо

```
:class = '{"active-section": b.active}'
```

Динамически изменять стили во vuejs?

Comment: В Вашем примере, не стили меняются, а класс.

Comment: Что именно вам нужно? Тот же класс ещё так можно `:class="[if_condition] ? 'first_class' : 'second_class' "`, если несколько классов - обернуть их в []

Comment: Не очень нравится, что IDE не узнает эти стили WebStorm. Поэтому возникла мысль, что это костыль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну JetBrains активно работают над поддержкой Vue в WebStrom. Динамические стили меняются через `:style`. Подсказки для JS синтаксиса CSS свойств (pascalCase) какие-никакие все же есть и сейчас. Классы пока что не дополняются даже для SFC.

[image: :style="{ paddingT }"]